# Accept multiple baseHref's in Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to know how I can have angular accept multiple baseHref's. For example, if I have my url as `usa/en/home` where `'/usa'` is the baseHref, how can I also accept something like `'uk/en/home'` and have angular register uk as a valid baseHref that it can build a route on?

Answer (score 0):

By using `@angular/localize` you can accomplish this. It build's multiple copies of your app with different base hrefs. If you set it up with two languages 'usa' and 'uk' it will build your project twice but with a different base href. The docs are [here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n).